# How to generate unique serial number in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, serialization, eloquent, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to build an application for my client where my client wants to keep all the data of his customer. He wants to generate a unique serial number for his customer and that serial number has to be sequential. His requirements are-
1. there should be a form to create a customer entry.
2. in that form there should be a field for unique customer id. By default it's value should be a serial number which value is +1 the previous serial number.And If he likes he may change the serial in that field and submit the form.

I found a easier way to do this is that get the max id from database and increment it +1. But what if two person trying to insert entry into db? in that case there would be duplicate serial number in the database.

Now, I want some help to know how to generate a unique and sequential serial number for each entry. I'll use mysql database.

thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly you need to edit your question to include sample codes. Your question is not very clear. If you are trying to generate a random number in laravel you can use str_random(40); function. 40 here is the length of string to generate

Comment: OP is not trying to generate a random string.

Comment: And question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create an additional table with one column for serial numbers.  Each time the form loads, you would grab the max serial number +1 from this table and insert that value as well and set the value of the serial number field on your form to that value.  This will make sure when two people load up your form at the same time, they will still have different serial numbers.  This will prevent the people who will be inserting data from feeling like they need to race each other to get that serial number in there first.

Secondly, on the table which is responsible for storing the form information, put a unique key on the serial number field and this will ensure that the serial number will always be unique when inserted into the table.

Thirdly, trying to insert a non-unique serial number into this table now will generate a sql error because of the unique key.  Before trying to save the form data, make sure you validate it by using the `unique` validator.